# Xcode shows a lot of errors in project but builds fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I have a problem in the project. After some moment I've realised that a lot of errors appears after indexing. All that errors are the problems with linking in the project (something like: use of undeclared identifier and etc. but when you `cmd + click` on the name of some buggy class everything is fine). After project is build errors disappear but then if I start surfing through the project, all errors appear again. It's very annoying.

**Solutions that I've tried to fix this with no luck:**

- Clean the project
- Clean the Derived Data
- I think it's somehow related to `Prefix.pch` file. I've check that all paths in project file are fine.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: post screen shot of errors you getting

Comment: @KAR check the pic

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem I deleted the #import lines from the pch file and recompiled which failed as expected then rewrite the deleted line and build again and it compiled without any error

Comment: this will help until you continue surfing through the project